# Plot histogram for each df column with overlapping outlines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am having some trouble creating a set of histograms. I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns. The last column is binary. I would like to the display the first 9 columns as histograms. Right now, I have df.hist() showing all 10 histograms as a set, which is fine.

But I want to customize this further. For example, for column 1 in my dataframe, I want its histogram to overlay the distribution where column 10 == 1 on top of the distribution where column 10 == 0. This binary column 10 would essentially be the legend for each of the 9 histograms. I also want to only show the histogram outlines (no fill) so you can see the two distributions on top of each other (red for 1, green for 0).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want 10 different histograms for 10 columns or a single histogram for 10 columns.

Comment: @Jeril, I’m hoping to achieve 9 different histograms (1 for each df column). If I could lay them out in something like a 3x3 grid, that would be great. In each of the 9 histograms, there would be two outlines (a red one for the df rows where the 10th column has a value of 1 and a green outline where the 10th df column has a value of 0). And a legend that shows “red (1)” and “green (0)”.

Comment: You can iterate the dataframe columns and plot using subplots. That will work. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Not yet, but I’ll give subplots a shot. Fairly new to matplotlib, so just hearing you mention subplots helps. I’ll try to set one column up the way I need and then do a for x in df.columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)

for ind, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[col].hist(ax=axes[ind % 3, int(ind / 3)])
```

You can use `df.columns` or you can iterate a list of columns that you want.